# MySQLdb : why does .commit() don't change the result of a query on another client?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm using MySQLdb on two computers and connect it to the same MySQL database. This database contains a database named `dbtest` with a table `test` with 50 rows, defined as following :

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    val varchar(255)
)
```

I use the interpreter in order to setup the problem :

```
# Run this on the 2 computers Python interpreter :
import MySQLdb
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="<database hostname>", user="root", passwd="<root password>")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("USE dbtest")
print cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test")  # will print 50.
```

All right. The two connections are setup. Now let's add a row with the first client :

```
# Run this on computer 1 :
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (val) VALUES ('gosh stackoverflow is so good !')")
connection.commit()
print cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test")  # will print 51.
```

Sounds good, WireShark prints the 51 rows returned by the database. But with the computer 2...

```
# Run this on computer 2 :
print cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test")  # will print 50, expected 51 because of the insert.
```

Why do I have 50 lines here ? How to avoid this issue ?

Sorry if it's a duplicate, I probably didn't find the right keywords.

EDIT: If I reset the connection on computer 2, I have the 51 lines.

Comment: Uuh... Found that just after : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305669/mysql-python-connection-does-not-see-changes-to-database-made-on-another-connect?rq=1 I'm currently trying.

Comment: Alright, the answer on the above link works. Then why do we have to BEGIN a transaction ?